# Import data from File to Cassandra Cluster with 5 nodes causes BusyConnectionException

Tags: java, cassandra, connection-pooling, datastax-java-driver

For my thesis, I need to upload data from a file to Cassandra Cluster. with session.execute() it too slow. So I decide to use session.executeAsyn(). but it causes BusyConnectionException.

Here is my code in Java:

```
    final PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
    poolingOptions.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768)
            .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 32768);
    final Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
            .addContactPoint("x.x.x.x")
            .withPort(9042)
            .build();
    final Session session = cluster.connect();
    System.out.println("session object---" + session.getState());
    final String path = "&PathToFile%";
    final File dir = new File(path);

    session.execute("use products;");
    for (final File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String str;
        final String insert = br.readLine();
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            final String query = insert + str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + "IF NOT EXISTS ;";
            session.executeAsync(query);
        }
    }
    session.close();
    cluster.close();
}
```

here are the exceptions that I had when I execute the Code:

> Error querying /x.x.x.1:9042 : com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [/x.x.x.1] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)
>       Error querying /x.x.x.2:9042 : com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [/x.x.x.2] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)
>       Error querying /x.x.x.3:9042 : com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [/x.x.x.3] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)
>       Error querying /x.x.x.4:9042 :  com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [/x.x.x.4] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)
>       Error querying /x.x.x.5:9042 : com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [/x.x.x.5] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)

Comment: What does `ulimit -a` on the CLI of this system return? Also check [this](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Busy exception occurs when you put too many request on one connection. You need to control how many requests are sent. Simplest way will be to use semaphore or something like. I [have a class](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/bootcamp/SessionLimiter.java) that wraps the `Session` and allows to control the number of inflight requests, so it behaves like async until you reach the limit, and will block until the number of in-flight requests will go under the limit. You can use my code, or implement something similar.

Update: You're using the [light-weight transactions (LWT)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html) (the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause), and this is heavily affect performance of your cluster because every insert need to be coordinated with other nodes...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use your class shall I delete this part with poolingOptions? 
so I used  your class so :
`final Session session = cluster.connect();
final SessionLimiter sl = new SessionLimiter(session, 20);
` 
and i replaced the sesseion.executeAsyn with session.execute(). Its wright?

Comment: No, you just need to wrap sessioin into `SessionLimiter` as you can see here: https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/bootcamp/DataLoader.java#L44, and then call `sl.executeAsync` instead of `session.executeAsync`... And you don't need to specify the number of requests - it will be fetched from Cluster's configuration

Comment: I did it but its too slow. :/

Comment: 30/s .
Debug:
`Connection[/x.x.x.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat`
`Connection[/x.x.x.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded`
`....` 
I think it works at only this node(x.x.x.1) because there is no information about the other nodes.

Comment: Switch to use prepared statements instead of generating queries for every line

Comment: the files that i generate are huge (about 4Gb) thats why i execute it with lines.

Comment: I'm talking about prepared statements - check the documentation for description

Comment: It works with your SessionLimiter class. Thank you so much !! U saved my Life